# Ubuntu Virtual Box black screen at boot

Tags: boot, server, virtualbox, login, virtualization

We have VirtualBox (latest version) running on an Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS Server.
On the VirtualBox we have several VB guests several OS like OpenBSD...

VirtualBox has been installed from repository no issues.
We have one VB guest with Ubuntu 18.04.02 we can startup the Ubuntu Guest and see is starting.
However half way through startup the screen goes black if we wait we can login to the guest (screen is still black) and shutdown the guest.
We are a bit stuck what we are missing in order to get it running.

The Ubuntu guest has been moved from a windows host to the ubuntu host with the Import/Export Appliance options in the File menu of VirtualBox.

We already done:

- assigned more memory, CPU cores, video memory
- checked the Ubuntu version 64Bit
- enabled/disabled 3D Acceleration

The OpenBSD Guests just run fine no issues with them.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities, namely between the EFI partition error because it is deleted or damaged so it must be formatted or not the boot file in it? Because the partition on Windows has an effect on EFI in virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

Windows and Ubuntu handle Hyper-V differently - as in, Ubuntu doesn't run on a hypervisor also running *nix. Neither does Windows work in a *nix-powered hypervisor as all. I believe disabling VT-d in the VM and related Hyper-V stuff may work.